# FastAPI fetch User and token from Azure

Tags: python, azure, fastapi

Im building an API using FastAPI and [`fastapi-azure-auth`](https://intility.github.io/fastapi-azure-auth/)

I followed the tutorials, and my openAPI/docs endpoints are protected. If I try to access any protected endpoint I am redirected to the Microsoft login page, and then I am able to use those endpoints.

What I am trying to do next is an endpoint which fetches an User object (which includes a token) which is called from the frontend. Then the front will use this User to call the authenticated endpoints.

I have been trying for days using the mentioned package, making calls to Azure, but all I manage is to get a "default" token.

I just want to simply click a link, let Azure authenticate the person, and return the User object with the information

Answer (score 0):

- you can use MSAL to get the azure tokens for auth.
- To this you will need the client Id, tenant Id from you registered azure ad app and username, password of your account.
- Now we can use `PublicClientApplication` to create a client and then use `acquire_token_by_username_password` to get the tokens.

```
from  msal  import  PublicClientApplication

clientid = ''
tenantid = ''
USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''

scope = [ '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default' ]

app = PublicClientApplication(
    client_id = clientid,
    authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantid
)

acquire_tokens_result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    username = USERNAME,
    password = ,
    scopes = scope
)

print(acquire_tokens_result['access_token'])
```

- Also, you need to configure `Allow public client flows` under `authentication` tab in the azure ad registered app.

[image]